# Data is not shown in QGIS2Web

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I've loaded a dataset in QGIS. It is shown in the QGIS window, however when I try to make a webpage out of it through the plug-in 'QGIS2web', the data is not shown (right) in the preview window as well as on the exported webpage. If I try Leaflet, the only thing shown is this infinite red line shown in the picture.

[image: Screenshot of preview webpage in qgis2web]

The picture below shows my window in QGIS. If I try OpenLayers or Mapbox, nothing is shown at all. Also, it is loading very very slowly into qgis2web.

[image: screenshot of data in QGIS]

Anyone has a clue what's happening here and how to fix it?

Comment: What projection is your data set to?

Comment: The Spatial Reference System (CRS) is set to earth, if that's what you mean? 
The properties panel sais this:
Method: Oblique Stereographic Alternative
celestial body: Earth

Comment: you will need to reproject the data so your data fits the output projection of the basemap.

Comment: In QGIS bottom right you see EPSG ... what is written there? Try setting EPSG 4326 and checking "v" in Match Project CRS in the Appearance tab of qgis2web. Actually export the data, don't just look at the preview.